# how to match a list of cidr blocks using java regex

Tags: java, regex, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to catch a list of CIDR blocks in a Cloudformation template (CF uses [enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-regexes.html) regex syntax.). The following so far catches 1 CIDR block:

```
(^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))$)
```

I am trying to catch 1 or more (comma separated, spaces are allowed between cidr blocks) using the following:

```
(^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))$)((, *)^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))$)*
```

but I am getting that the input string does not match the allowed pattern for the following input:

```
10.10.10.10/32, 20.20.20.20/32, 30.30.30.30/32
```

How can I match a list of cidr blocks, comma separated (space are accepted)? why my solution does not work? is it possible to reuse the first matching group and reuse it, so I don't need to rewrite it twice?

EDIT:
The best I can come up with is:

```
^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))(,+\s*([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2])))*$
```

but it catches also `10.10.10.10/32,`, the final comma should not be catched :(

Comment: for starters, `(^...$)*` can only have one match.  ^ and $ should be _outside_ the parentheses to match multiples on the innards.  Have you been using the regex101 website?  Highly recommended.  https://regex101.com/

Comment: Using `\G` you could use a single capturing group `\G((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/(?:3[0-2]|[1-2][0-9]|[0-9]))(?:, )?` See https://regex101.com/r/5KOo8R/1